# How to fetch the all the repo owner's name in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have 100 repositories in JFrog Artifactory, now I want to fetch all the owner's information. There is no CLI or JSON API to get such details from Artifactory.

Comment: Artifactory does not have a repository owner. Do you care about which users have permission for a given repository? have deployed artifacts to a repository?

Comment: Thanks Dror for the quick reply.we have 10 users and they are admin for their repo they created it in JFrog so I want to fetch who created which repo in JFrog.

Comment: You could try using the [Folder Info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FolderInfo) REST endpoint on the root (`/`) folder of the repository. Then you could look at the `createdBy` field. Whoever made the root folder would have also made the repository it belongs to. I haven't tried this though, so I don't know for certain whether or in what situations it would work.